# How to use substringof in azure-mobile-apps-js-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, odata, azure-mobile-services

I want to make use of odata substringof method using azure-mobile-apps-js-client.
Currently I use indexof method but want to switch to substringof.

**I have this code**

```
function queryFunction(term){
     return this.FullName.indexOf(term) != -1
}
table.where(queryFunction, term)
```

**Which translates to**

```
$filter=indexof(FullName, term) ne -1
```

**I need URL like this:**

```
filter=substringof(term, FullName) eq true
```

How do I do that with javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`azure-query-js` supports a limited set of Javascript functions that are translated to their odata equivalents. Currently, there is no function that can be mapped to `substringof`. Your original implementation using `indexOf` is your best bet for querying for substrings using Javascript style querying.

However, if you wish to take complete control of querying yourself, you can directly pass an OData query string to the `read` method. https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/blob/2b5e083d400a089cb1759d6d58d96e4d10ba2310/sdk/test/tests/shared/mobileServiceTables.js#L98 is an example. If you search for `'$filter'` in the file you will find a few more examples.

Comment: Also, note that the OData query string should be URL encoded. To fetch records where 'abc + def' is a substring of the text column, you would need to do something like: `table.read("$filter=substringof(%27abc%20%2B%20def%27,%20text)%20eq%20true")`