# azure-query.js indexof query not working

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to use index of to query my local table but it always returns no data even though the values do exist and there is data. What the is correct syntax to generate a local query with index of for azure mobile apps client js.

```
(indexof(name, '" + filterObject.searchString + "') ne -1)
```

That is the string generator I use. It returns no errors but returns no values either.

After multiple tests we decided to only use the library for pull/push data with server and use sqlite to query the local tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using [Javascript Clients for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library#table-reference), please try the following code to query a table with `indexOf` function.

```
var table = client.getTable('tableName'); 
table.where(function(startsWith) {
    return this.name.indexOf(startsWith) === 0;
}, filterObject.searchString).read().then(function(results) {
   console.log(results);
}, function(error) {
    throw new Error('Error loading data: ', error);
});
```

Comment: But that is to query a server table not a local table.

Comment: You may need to encode the OData query string. Please see Shrirang's comment on question: [How to use substringof in azure-mobile-apps-js-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076143/how-to-use-substringof-in-azure-mobile-apps-js-client/41111736#41111736).